# How to change text color on scroll for a bootstrap nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have tried for days now and cannot seem to get the text colour change for my nav bar on the scroll.

I have some Javascript and CSS already working so it changes the background colour of the nav bar but I cannot for the life of me change the text colour

You will see if adds and removes when the page moves y, I have tried adding in more if else statements, also tried changes classes around
I have left in the css where I link all the attached classes to the nav items, it does nothing but I have it added in so you can see what shows up attached to the text when I inspect on chrome.

```js
var navbar = document.querySelector('nav')

window.onscroll = function() {

    // pageYOffset or scrollY
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        navbar.classList.add('scrolled')
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove('scrolled')
    }
}
```

```css
.text-nav:hover {
    opacity: 1.9;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}



nav {
    height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #0003 70%,#0000); !* background when scroll is in the top *!*/
    transition: background .5s; /* control how smooth the background changes */
    /*transition: color .5s;*/
}
nav.scrolled {
    /*background: #b6b7b7;*/
    background: #1B1E21;
}


.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link.scrolled {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light main navbar-custom navbar-static-top ">
<!--    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link nav-space text-nav " href="">Home <span
                        class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-space text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-space text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>David2me</b></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active text-nav nav-space">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never added the class `.scrolled` to the links. I added them using `querySelectorAll` and iterated through them with `forEach`

```js
var navbar = document.querySelector('nav')
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')

window.onscroll = function() {

    // pageYOffset or scrollY
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        navbar.classList.add('scrolled')
        links.forEach(v => {
          v.classList.add('scrolled')
        });
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove('scrolled')
        links.forEach(v => {
          v.classList.remove('scrolled')
        });
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.text-nav:hover {
    opacity: 1.9;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}



nav {
    height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #0003 70%,#0000); !* background when scroll is in the top *!*/
    transition: background .5s; /* control how smooth the background changes */
    /*transition: color .5s;*/
}
nav.scrolled {
    /*background: #b6b7b7;*/
    background: #1B1E21;
}


.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link.scrolled {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light main navbar-custom navbar-static-top ">
<!--    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link nav-space text-nav " href="">Home <span
                        class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-space text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-space text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>David2me</b></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active text-nav nav-space">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active text-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This has worked, I feel silly now, I tried other functions but not that way. I'm still struggling with javascript, but thanks your answer has thought me something! My first question asked and I'm amazed at the response time! Isn't there a way to award the correct answer on this is there?

Comment: @DavidTwomey glad to help! You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues you are facing:

1. Your CSS selector is wrong. You have two select all nav-links that are in your nave bar with the `scrolled` class. So you have to check for the `scrolled` class on the nav element, not on the nav-link element: `nav.scrolled.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link`
2. Bootstrap is already applying a style to the nav-link element. In your case, it takes precedence over your custom class. To prevent this, you can use `color: white !important;` to give your color precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I got sorted with Rojo's answer but some good points to take from your response so I appreciate it all the same. Thank you.